# Button Responsiveness at UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am dynamically creating a uiscrollview and i place some uiview's that contains some label and buttons inside to display some news. Every button inside the sub uiview calls a rest function to like, unlike or share the news. Some of the buttons opens overlay screens like comment news. I am assigning actions to buttons inside the main form that contains the uiscrollview.

When i click a button that opens an overlay screen. When i close the overlay screen and hit Like button, it does not respond to touches. After attempting one or two more times, it works.

Does anyone has any idea about this issue?

Comment: Put an NSLog statement in your button handler to see if it's being called or not.  If it is, something's wrong downstream.  If it's not, there might be another clear view on top of the button, etc.

Comment: It is not working at first attempt. But after one or two attempts, it works. Maybe we are not tapping to exact same place and we are tapping   to an invisible overlay area? What do you think?

Comment: Thank you for your help. There was a clear view and that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using UITapGestureRecogniser for "Click action"? If yes, you propably want to set flag "cancelsTouchesInView = NO" for this recogniser.

Comment: Actually i am assigning the actions with [button1 addTarget...]

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if there is a clear view covering your button.  That view will consume your tap, so the button never sees it.